# How to change focus in X-window by terminal

Tags: xorg

I got the window id by using xwininfo command.
I want to change the focus of this window by a terminal command.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool). I have used it to resize browser windows.

```
$ xdotool windowfocus 0x280000a
```

Comment: It works. The sad thing is that I cannot install xdotool in the pc I want because I am not the admin. Is there any other (more standard) way?

Comment: Maybe ask your window manager. Also, can't be that big of a deal to compile it on whatever computer you want to use it? Or copy a binary.

Comment: Of course I would do that. But I can't even copy files to my pc. No usb, no cd, no internet connection :)

Comment: Αny suggestions without xdotool?

Comment: Do you have `wmctrl`?